# SQLite gives a correct length instead of a javascript length?

Tags: sqlite

I inserted an emoticon in a text field and the length is 1 instead of 2 as our almighty javascript said.

The emoticon size :

```
select length(\'\');
'length(\'\')': 1
```

How can I get SQLite to give the -correct- result in -UTF8- javascript, that is 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emoticon symbol consists of two UTF-16 code points (`\ud83c\udf49`) or four UTF-8 bytes (`F0 9F 8D 89`).

The Javascript `length` function returns the number of UTF-16 code points for the string:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

The SQLite `length` function returns the number of characters in the string:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length

In other words: they are two different functions.

If you are after the byte length of the string then you could use:

```
select length(cast('' as BLOB))
```

Output:

```
4
```

It is probably best to take a step back and review what you actually want to achieve; maybe there is a different approach.